# Function declaration within a function definition with wrong signature?

Tags: c, function, function-declaration

I have encountered the following code:

```
delete_list(list **l, item_type x)
{
    list *p; /* item pointer */
    list *pred; /* predecessor pointer */
    list *search_list(), *predecessor_list();

    p = search_list(*l,x);
    if (p != NULL) {
        pred = predecessor_list(*l,x);
        if (pred == NULL) /* splice out out list */
            *l = p->next;
        else
            pred->next = p->next;
        free(p); /* free memory used by node */
    }
}
```

I couldn't quite understand what this line means:

```
    list *search_list(), *predecessor_list();
```

Is this a function declaration? If yes;

1. Why is there a function declaration within a function? I thought that function declarations are supposed to be outside of all functions.
2. Why is the signature (parameters) of the declarations do not match how these functions are called in the code?

If this is not a function declaration, then what is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's a couple of function prototype declarations.

And as any declaration you can have them inside a function. It's function *definitions* (i.e. their implementation) you can't have inside other functions.

As for the argument mismatch, that's how C works. If you don't declare any arguments then the function will be declared to have an unknown number of arguments of unknown type, and you can really call them passing just about anything and the compiler won't know if it's right or wrong.

Comment: So everything is alright then. BTW, is there a difference between function _prototype_ declaration vs function declaration?

Comment: @Utku Yes everything is okay, and a function declaration and prototype declaration and function prototype declaration are just three ways to say the same thing.

Comment: Isn't the point that these are *not* prototypes, just declaration?

Comment: Joachim, will the scope of these prototyps be the function? (i.e. the prototypes are not known anymore outside the function?). I'm probably asking the obvious...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The scope of the declarations is only local inside the function yes. They could still be called from elsewhere if the compiler is working in pre-C99 mode, as then the declarations would be auto-deduced at the time of the call (often unreliably, which is why it was removed in the C99 standard).